# Is it good to index category in search engines?

Tags: seo, search-engines, duplicate-content

I have a Wordpress blog.

Is it good to index category in search engines? Will it cause duplicate content issue?

I'm little scared about Panda Google algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean by category. The category of your posts?